# Using a random number to select a variable

Tags: swift

I have two variables, `string0` and `string1`. I want to randomly set a label to one of those strings. I tried generating the variable name using a random number like this:

```
let string0a = "\(Name!) sees something that offends \(Gender!)."

let string1a = "\(Name!) saw Star Wars earlier."

let number = arc4random_uniform(1)
text1.text = string\(number!)a
```

What is the best way to randomly set the label text to one of the two strings?

Comment: Most languages don't allow operations of this type with variable names. You  might be better generating a random number and then using an if statement to select one of the two strings. Alternatively, you might want to add the strings, 2 or more, to an array and use the generated number to select an element at the random index.

Comment: As a solution: place them into one array and get by index

Comment: Could you please provide the code to access them at an index? I'm fairly new to swift, thanks!

Comment: `var firstItem = shoppingList[0]` from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID107

Answer (score 1):

You can't generate variable names at runtime in Swift because they are used at compile time.  This is what arrays were invented for:

```
let strings = [string0a, string1a]

let number = Int(arc4random_uniform(2))

text1.text = strings[number]
```

or more concisely:

```
text1.text = [string0a, string1a][Int(arc4random_uniform(2))]
```

Comment: Note that with `.._uniform(1)`, `number` will always have the value `0`.

Comment: @dfri, yep, I just modified OP's code without thinking about it.